# Error 500 when trying to save data to Mongodb database using Prisma in NextJS app

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, next.js, prisma, next-auth

I am creating a simple app in NextJS that can save and fetch data from mongodb using prisma but I've run into some issues when trying to create a new db entry.

I am trying to save a new listing but I keep getting the 500 error. I think it's due to the relational data.

I have tried debugging but I am not having any luck

prisma/schema.prisma

```
import {
    NextResponse
} from "next/server";
import prisma from "@/libs/prismadb";
import {
    getSession
} from "next-auth/react";
export default async function POST(req: any, res: any) {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        console.log('wrong page') return res.status(405).end(); // Method not allowed 
    }
    try {
        const session = await getSession({
            req
        });
        if (!session) {
            return NextResponse.redirect("/login");
        }
        const body = req.body;
        const {
            title,
            description,
            price,
            image
        } = body;
        console.log(session?.user?.id)
        const user = await prisma.listing.create({
            data: {
                title,
                description,
                price,
                image,
                senderId: session?.user?.id,
            },
        });
        return res.status(200).json(user);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        if (err instanceof Error) {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: err.message
            });
        } else {
            return res.status(500).json({
                message: 'An unexpected error occurred'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

api/listings.tsx

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import prisma from "@/libs/prismadb";
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";

export default async function POST(req: any, res: any) {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        console.log('wrong page')

      return res.status(405).end(); // Method not allowed
    }
    
    try {

      const session = await getSession({ req });
    
    if(!session){
        return NextResponse.redirect("/login");
    }

    const body = req.body;
    const { title, description, price, image } = body;
    console.log(session?.user?.id)

    
    
      const user = await prisma.listing.create({
        data: {
            title,
            description,
            price,
            image,
            senderId: session?.user?.id,
        },
      });
  
      return res.status(200).json(user);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      
      if (err instanceof Error) {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: err.message });
      } else {
        return res.status(500).json({ message: 'An unexpected error occurred' });
      }
    }
  }
```

```
const ListingModal = () => {
        const {
            register,
            handleSubmit,
            formState: {
                errors
            },
            reset,
            watch,
            setValue
        } = useForm < FieldValues > ({
            defaultValues: {
                title: "",
                description: "",
                price: "",
                category: "",
                image: "",
                senderId: "",
            },
        });
        const onSubmit: SubmitHandler < FieldValues > = async (data: any) => {
            setIsLoading(true);
            console.log(data);
            await axios.post('/api/listings', data).then(() => {
                toast.success('Offer created successfully!');
                router.refresh();
                reset();
                offerModal.onClose();
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log('Something went wrong!');
            }).finally(() => {
                setIsLoading(false);
            });
        };
 ... };
```

I ran a console.log on the form data and it was correctly passing to the SubmitHander but the api call is failing. If anyone could help me it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you share the exact error message that you get?